apache-iceberg fixing found conflicting files that can contain records matching true
When running a Merge into query the error
org.apache.iceberg.exceptions.ValidationException: Found conflicting files that can contain records matching true: [file_1, file_2, file_3]

pops up.
I want to know what is the proper way of fixing this issue, as I understand that directly deleting files will mess with the iceberg metadata. I know the problem as stated is a bit general, but also I cannot find anything in documentation or other discussions about how to even start fixing a similar issue.
Closest discussion I found is related to the catalog cache: https://github.com/apache/iceberg/issues/3559, But I think this may be a different issue as that thread is about simultaneous merges creating a conflict on the cache, but my present problem is persistent across sessions.
Now, for the specifics of my issue, I am working with AWS Athena and AWS Glue, the issue started after using athena to erase the contents of a column via an update statement:
update table1 SET column1 = NULL

And the error messaged appeared after trying to run a spark merge into statement on an AWS Glue job to repopulate the column.
I suspect the issue probably boils down to AWS Athena not handling the iceberg table update correctly, and leaving files active that should have been marked as old on the metadata files.
I tried rolling back to an earlier snapshot but it didn't solve the issue.

Following the github discussion (https://github.com/apache/iceberg/issues/3559), I tried disabling the Spark Catalog Cache, but it did not solve the issue, still the error could possibly be related to concurrent writes.
So I decided to stop another script that was running every 10 minutes, replicating some CDC data to the table, and the merge query ran without an issue, suggesting this could be a concurrency issue.
To optimize concurrent writers to the same table it is recommended to change the isolation level to snapshot (https://iceberg.apache.org/javadoc/0.11.0/org/apache/iceberg/IsolationLevel.html), I made that configuration change and it seems to have solved the issue.
